# Check if all values in a map are equal

Tags: java, dictionary

I need to check if all values in a map are equal. I have a method to perform this task but would like to use a library or native methods. Limitations: Java 5 + Apache Commons libraries.

```
public static boolean isUnique(Map<Dboid,?> aMap){

boolean isUnique = true;
Object currValue = null;
int iteration = 0;

Iterator<?> it = aMap.entrySet().iterator();

while(it.hasNext() && isUnique){
    iteration++;
    Object value = it.next();
    if(iteration > 1){
        if (value != null && currValue == null ||
            value == null && currValue != null ||
            value != null && currValue != null & !value.equals(currValue)) {
            isUnique = false;
        }
    }
    currValue = value;
}
return isUnique;
}
```

Comment: You can improve your own method though.  
Code suggested by a_horse_with_no_name will do the job but it will create a separate HashSet and copy possibly all your values into that HashSet in the process.
All you need to do is get the first element and compare it to all other elements (foreach loop will be useful here) until you find one that does **not** equals the value of the first one. As soon as you find not equal element you can break out of the loop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about this something like this:

```
Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>(aMap.values());
boolean isUnique = values.size() == 1;
```

Comment: That won't scale well to lots of elements that *aren't* unique.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Then they are obviously not equal.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: it won't be slower than the code in the question I assume.

Comment: Maybe ```values.size() <= 1``` would be better. I think that empty map could be also considered as a solution.
@DavidEhrmann: It can be very slow depending on implementation of ```equals()``` and ```hashCode()```

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj: I thought about that too, but I think it's better to simply have a `if (aMap.isEmpty()) return true` as pre-condition in the method.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name slower, ~no, but it takes a lot more memory than needed.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
return (new HashSet(aMap.values()).size() == 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the original questions asks for solutions in Java 5, but in case someone else searching for an answer to this question is not limited to Java 5 here is a Java 8 approach.

```
return aMap.values().stream().distinct().limit(2).count() < 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could *store* the values in a [Bidirectional Map](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) and always have this property.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment above:

```
//think in a more proper name isAllValuesAreUnique for example
    public static boolean isUnique(Map<Dboid,?> aMap){
         if(aMap == null)
               return true; // or throw IlegalArgumentException()

         Collection<?> c = aMap.getValues(); 
         return new HashSet<>(c).size() <= 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isUnique(Map<Dboid,?> aMap) {
    Set<Object> values = new HashSet<Object>();

    for (Map.Entry<Dboid,?> entry : aMap.entrySet()) {
      if (!values.isEmpty() && values.add(entry.getValue())) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This solution has the advantage to offer a memory-saving short cut if there are many differences in the map. For the special case of an empty `Map` you might choose `false` as return value, change it appropriately for your purpose.

Or even better without a `Set` (if your `Map` does not contain null-values):

```
public static boolean isUnique(Map<Dboid,?> aMap) {
    Object value = null;

    for (Object entry : aMap.values()) {
      if (value == null) {
        value = entry;
      } else if (!value.equals(entry)) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
}
```